# Getting Meeting by ICalUid in EWS

Tags: xml, soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to send a bare bones SOAP request to my Exchange 2010 SP2 server, in order to find a meeting by ICalUid, inspired by [this great answer by Glen](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/1f623537-03ce-486e-8e33-4df38b513017/find-an-event-with-a-specific-uid-using-exchange-web-services-2010).

```
'<soap:Envelope ' +
'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
'xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" ' +
'xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" ' +
'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
'  <soap:Header>' +
'    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP2"/>' +
'  </soap:Header>' +
'  <soap:Body>' +
'    <m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">' +
'      <m:ItemShape>' +
'        <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>' +
'      </m:ItemShape>' +
'      <m:Restriction>' +
'        <t:IsEqualTo>' +
'          <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="Meeting" PropertyId="0x03" PropertyType="Binary"/>' +
'          <t:FieldURIOrConstant>' +
'            <t:Constant Value="bbkpr55lqbc49acfg9objhg40g" />' +
'          </t:FieldURIOrConstant>' +
'        </t:IsEqualTo>' +
'      </m:Restriction>' +
'      <m:ParentFolderIds>' +
'        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="calendar" />' +
'      </m:ParentFolderIds>' +
'    </m:FindItem>'
'  </soap:Body>' +
'</soap:Envelope>';
```

This gives rise to the following error:

`The 'PropertyId' attribute is invalid - The value '0x03' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:int' - The string '0x03' is not a valid Int32 value.`

It is obviously not an `Int32` value, but why is not the `PropertyType="Binary"` having any effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `3` instead of `0x03` in your request XML.  The `PropertyId` *in the request itself* is defined as an `int`, and the XML definition [doesn't allow hex encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-2-20010502/#int) of `int` types.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I don't know why I didn't make that connection. Looking closer at the managed API it transforms the hex value to an integer as you say. Thank you very much dkarp!