# Getting Google Event in Exchange Calendar with EWS

Tags: calendar, exchange-server, icalendar, exchangewebservices

To get an event from an Exchange calendar by `ICalUId`, you can use the [FindItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa566107(v=exchg.150).aspx)-operation, using the UId `base64-encoded` as value to the Extended property identified by
[DistinguishedPropertySetId=Meeting,  PropertyId=3 and PropertyType=Binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692302/getting-meeting-by-icaluid-in-ews).

This works great for events that are created in the Exchange calendar, where `ICalUIds` look like the following: `040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000A7C552582821D1010000000000000000100000002550ED442EB2CF4287FD94D10A4F331D`

However, this does not work when trying to get the event with a Google Calendar UId, which looks like the following:
`tp90m1srk847n1oa4jtp9ofou0@google.com`

Not even using the substring before `@google.com` works, sadly.

Is there a way to get Google Events in the Exchange Calendar with EWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GlobalObjectId is generated from the UID in this case using the formula defined in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee157690(v=exchg.80).aspx . So if all you have is the UID you will need to generate the GlobalObjectId to search using your own algorithm. eg

```
        String UId = "k5abv4oduaidu8knel4088iq8c@google.com";
        String Header = "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E008";
        String Padding = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
        String Prefix = "7643616C2D55696401000000";
        String DataString = Prefix + BitConverter.ToString(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(UId)).Replace("-", "") + "00";
        String BigEndianlength = (DataString.Length / 2).ToString("X8");
        String LittleEndianlength = BigEndianlength.Substring(6, 2) + BigEndianlength.Substring(4, 2) + BigEndianlength.Substring(2, 2) + BigEndianlength.Substring(0, 2);
        String GlobalUidHex = Header + Padding + LittleEndianlength + DataString;
```

If you then conver the HexString to Base64 String that should work.

Cheers
glen

Comment: Thanks Glen. Do you happen to have any resource on the format of the `DataString`? I can't get this to work, and I suspect that is the culprit in my code.

Comment: Use a Mapi Editor like OutlookSpy to look at the value of the property you should be able to work it out (eg you should the google UID with the property Value.Recurring appointment maybe a bit different you need to look at the spec.